# Tax charged for virtual products only order

Tags: orders, virtual-products, ce-1.9.2.1

I'm having a strange issue with orders containing only virtual products.
I have configured tax-calculation to be based on shipping address.

> configuration -> tax -> calculation settings -> tax calculation based
>   on -> shipping address

Although, tax is still applied for the virtual products.
I have found another question regarding the opposite situation ([tax not applied for virtual products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/virtual-products-not-being-taxed)) - now I'm quite puzzled why it does not work here as intended (-> no tax for virtual orders).

Any ideas what may be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the product's tax class in the admin, on the product edit page, Price section, Tax Class dropdown; the value should be **None**.

Comment: hm, not what i was looking for :/

Comment: What's your expected behavior?

Comment: expected behavior is described here in the question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/virtual-products-not-being-taxed

Comment: It's still unclear to me if you want tax to be applied for your virtual products or not. If you **do NOT** want tax on your virtual products, then setting their Tax Class to **None** should fix it. If you **do** want tax on your virtual products, then setting `tax calculated based on` `Billing Address` and Tax Class to `Taxable Goods` should do the trick.

Comment: What I want to achieve is not standard i guess. Due to our requirements, tax calculation is based on shipping address. As virtual products only orders do not have any shipping address, it is unclear what happens. At the moment the tax gets calculated, even though the order has no shipping address and should not calculate Tax. On the other side, we do want tax for inland orders (based on billing address) but not for foreign countries. Seems like I have to do a hack here.